# Underlying functor U:K-Coalg → K-Mod preserves colimits.

Tags: category-theory

I am stuck with the following theorem:

> **Theorem :** Let $K$ be a commutative ring, and let $U \colon K\mathrm{-Coalg} \to K\mathrm{-Mod}$ be the underlying functor from the category of $K$-coalgebras $K\mathrm{-Coalg}$  to the category of $K$-modules $K\mathrm{-Mod}$. Then $U$  preserves colimits.

Could you guys help me to prove this theorem (with out assuming that $U$ has a right adjoint)?

Dan

Comment: btw, nobody would call this a "Theorem".

Answer (score 4):

This comes simply from the observation that $U$ creates colimits and K-Mod has all colimits.

(More generally, any comonadic functor creates colimits)

Comment: Could you guys explain more how can U create colimits since I have no idea about comonadic functor. 
Thanks, 
Dan

Comment: You don't have to know comonadic functors. You only have to know the definitions. What have you tried? It's straight forward to check that $U$ creates colimits. Just dualize the usual proof (see Mac Lane etc.) that the forgetful functor from algebras to modules creates limits.